# Converting all spin along $z$ axis to spin along $x$ axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

In a Stern Gerlach experiment, suppose initially we prepare electrons all having spin along z-axis and we want them "all" to have spin along x-axis, how can we do this by applying a magnetic field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is *not* via a Stern-Gerlach configuration (which, in its essence, is a [projective measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics)), but rather via unitary evolution as described by the Schrödinger equation.

What you really want is to perform what's known as a $\pi/2$ pulse about the $y$ axis, and this can be implemented by a short pulse of magnetic field $\mathbf B=B_y\hat{\mathbf e}_y$. This will cause the spins to precess about the $y$ axis, and you just turn the field off when you've achieved a 90° rotation and the spins that were along $+z$ are now at $+x$.

Answer (score 1):

By rotating them continuously in a magnetic field that rotates smoothly in direction along the path of travel. (As opposed to changing direction instantaneously, or more realistically, reducing to zero and the increasing in the transverse direction).